# Как заставить работать postfix после обновления до mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql, freebsd, postfix

На freebsd 10 установлен iredmail, обновил mysql 5.6 до 5.7

> service postfix start

Shared object "libmysqlclient.so.18" not found, required by "postfix"

> /usr/ports/mail/postfix # make reinstall

postfix-2.11.7,1 cannot install: MySQL versions mismatch: mysql57-client
is installed and wanted version is mysql56-client.
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/ports/mail/postfix

Как заставить postfix работать с mysql 5.7?

Comment: самый простой и первым приходящий в голову путь: вернуть всё так, как было.

Comment: 5.7 был поставлен для увеличения производительности, т.к. на этом сервере еще сайт есть, что собственно он и делает, но хотелось бы чтобы работало все.

Comment: значит, и postfix надо пересобрать, вероятно, внеся необходимые коррективы.

Comment: @Magi да, постфикс надо просто пересобрать, что бы подцепил новую библиотеку. Скажите вашему установщику пакетов его обновить, например. Как вариант можно сделать в /usr/lib (или где у вас библиотеки mysql лежат) ссылку libmysqlclient.so.18 указывающую на новую версию библиотеки (там наверняка какая нибудь .so.19 или с большим номером появилась). Но так делать в общем то не рекомендуется